# wiederum vs. widerum

Tags: spelling

I have a problem with the correct spelling, IMHO the **ie** is wrong, however the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wiederum) states it is the correct one. I want to give an example:

> Die einen finden das Bild schön, die anderen widerum hässlich.

The word here is rather used as a contradiction (Widerspruch) than a repetition (Wiederholung), so why should it be written with "ie" then? Or do you see it different? All the efforts of explanations in the web are rather lousy.

Comment: Logic only applies partially to languages. Why.. questions are always difficult to answer.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think that *logic* fails, I would say : ) It's only superficial or wrong understanding. E.g. expecting to find regular patterns, where they might not exist. Language has rather that right.

Comment: The repepetition for "wieder" comes from the "(r)um" - "if we turn the issue around and look again, there is another point of view"

Comment: Ich hab' ne Weile Schnaps probiert, jetzt trink ich wieder Rum.

Answer (score 2):

Note, that [Grimm's Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW19922#XGW19922) consistently writes *Wi(e)der...* for practically all similar words, so you can at least claim historical correctness.

Since the same word *wiederum* is meaning repetition as well as oppositeness, you could well argue, that two different words would be more appropriate. But adjusting the spelling to one meaning on cost of the other is somewhat adventurous, given that Duden only provides the *wiederum* spelling.

Comment: Making decision on costs of something minor is common in our world  but in this special case it was the major side which was dropped.
But I feel honored to be in the same boat with Grimms. At least for a millisecond. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

"Wider" and "wieder" are etymologically the same word. The different spellings of "wi(e)derum" are thus not governed by logic, or by etymology, but purely by convention. Look at the "Etymologie" section here:

https://www.dwds.de/wb/wider

Answer (score 1):

It's a repetition.

You can say:

> Die einen finden das Bild schön, die anderen wiederum hässlich.
>   Die einen finden das Bild schön, die anderen wieder hässlich.
>   Die einen finden das Bild schön, die anderen anderseits hässlich.

- anderseits (otherwise or but then again / then again / But then, ... ?)

The word again (wieder) means a repetition.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. The [help] will answer most unanswered questions about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling rules are about conventions, and about the frequencies how a word is used. Only recently we tried to introduce some logic to the latest spelling reform but as we all know how this logic also fails at times.

There are always reasons making a given spelling look more sensible than the other. We can for example ask why it isn't spellt [**widerrum**](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22widerrum%22&rct=j) just like [Widerruf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Widerruf) is. Some people do this, but most don't. Most people spell it [**wiederum**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wiederum). That is just about all there is to our spelling rules.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't about contradiction or not but whether a word is derived from the *wieder* or the *wider* root. Wiederum is derived from *wieder*, that's why it's always written with ie. Regardless whether the meaning is *again* or *on the other hand*.

Stupid German language. Sorry.

Comment: Warum? Weil Ironie manch einen überfordern könnte?

Comment: Ich halte das Herumeditieren in den Beiträgen anderer für eine sehr mächtige Funktion, die nur in allergrößter Not eingesetzt werden sollte.

Comment: @Janka: [help](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/editing) disagrees with your viewpoint: *Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date.*

Comment: Help also suggest not to be rude in editing. Oh wait, it **does not**.

Comment: @Janka: But who and when was it decided it has to be derived from "wieder", I think my question even has doubt in this and only because it was decided once, it does not become more valid.
PS: Your joke was ok for me. Still like the riddles of German language, it is rather like a challenge to know it. ;-)

Comment: Iris, I meant to acknowledge Thomas that wiederrum vs. widerum is one of those illogical, stupid things in the German language learners become desperate of. Acknowledging this with some irony, I hoped to make him feel better about that. Deleting that sentence deleted my consolation.

Comment: @Thomas: I bet this has happened even before https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1876 because they discussed replacing -iren by -ieren then.

Comment: Do you have sources to support your claim of deriving *wiederum* from the *wieder* root?

Comment: Well. It's spelling?

Comment: Hier steht, dass _wiederum_ von _wieder_ kommt: https://m.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/widerum.shtml und http://wortwuchs.net/schreibweise/wiederum-widerum/

Comment: @Iris But the [etymologic dictionary entry on DWDS.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wieder#et-1) claims that both *wieder* and *wider* derive from a **common root.** Thus, there is no such thing as different *wieder* and *wider* roots; it was merely a novel orthographic distinction made some time in German’s (not Germanic’s or Indo-European’s) history. I conclude, after having searched for the source, that this answer is misleading and wrong; thus –1.

Comment: This isn't about the historical root of *wieder* and *wider* (which is indeed common), but about the root of the word *wiederum* in the same word pool as *wieder* and *wider*. In that same word-pool *wiederum* clearly is derived from *wieder* and not from *wider*. When you go back in time far enough you would find both words have their origin in *bah* or another utterance not relevant for today's speaking.